# ng-Selected functionality not working in Kendo Dropdown

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-dropdown

I have two options like '+' and '-' in Select Tag. Here is my Code

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list k-ng-model="Directions">
<option ng-selected="Direction==0" value="0">+</option>
<option ng-selected="Direction==1" value="1">-</option>
</select>
```

when removing the 'kendo-drop-down-list' in select tag ng-select is working fine.

I want to keep kendo-drop-down-list along with ng-select should work.